# What other whitepapers are there for coin distribution models like POW (proof of work) and POS (proof of stake)?

Tags: proof-of-work, proof-of-stake

I'm looking for other types of distribution models for crypto coins that are like POW (proof of work) and POS (proof of stake). I'm assuming these are a type of distribution model for coins, or is there a better term for it? I mainly want to find other systems that have unique ways of distributing a coin. Is there a list somewhere?

Comment: A nice collection of crypto-related white papers: http://encryptopedia.com/?s=proof+of&submit=Search

Answer (score 10):

I don't know of any such list yet, but no reason we can't start making one. :) Others should feel free to add their findings via an edit.

- [Proof of Work](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf)
- [Proof of Stake](http://www.peercoin.net/assets/paper/peercoin-paper.pdf)
- [Proof of Activity](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/452.pdf)
- [Proof of Storage](http://storj.io/storj.pdf)
- [Proof of Knowledge](https://www.reddit.com/r/ziftrCOIN/comments/2wlg5l/ziftrcoin_mining_update_proof_of_knowledge/)
- [Proof of Stake Velocity](https://www.reddcoin.com/papers/PoSV.pdf)
- [Proof of Burn](https://slimcoin.org/index.php/en/resources-en/proof-of-burn)
- [Dual Purpose Proof of Work](http://primecoin.io/bin/primecoin-paper.pdf) (Primecoin)
- [Proof of Lock](http://tendermint.com/docs/tendermint.pdf) (Tendermint)
- [Delegated Proof of Stake](https://bitshares.org/blog/delegated-proof-of-stake/) (Bitshares)
- [Stellar Consensus Protocol](https://www.stellar.org/papers/stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf) (Stellar)
- [Xoken Consensus Protocol](http://www.xoken.org/knowledge-base/) (Xoken)

Comment: Non-Snake-Oil version of Proof of Stake : https://download.wpsoftware.net/bitcoin/pos.pdf (recently updated)

Comment: @Jannes, that doc seems to be more of an anti-PoS doc than a proposal for a modified security scheme.

Comment: Warning people to think twice, before investing time or money in something overhyped yet unproven and even long discarded as impossible by people in the know, seems only fair. (They got sick of explaining this to people over and over again, that's why they wrote this paper.)

Comment: We can add "Proof of Luck": https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=442626.0;wap2 and https://github.com/nejucomo/cryptocurrencydesign/wiki/Proof-of-Luck

Comment: More recent discussion for Proof of Luck: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1087219.0

Comment: @sw. Taking a quick look at those links makes me think that this is more like buying a scratch ticket than a distribution scheme for a coin.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, there's been an update to the POS protocol that many coins are adopting: http://blackcoin.co/blackcoin-pos-protocol-v2-whitepaper.pdf

v3 in the works

Answer (score -2):

Here is an interesting new whitepaper.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01341.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you Andrew and Pieter for your instructive feedback!